# ansible: filter one element of the list to string

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template, ansible-filter

ansible 2.9.13

Need to add to the remote file string like  `MyIP = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Here is a test template:

```
MyIP = {{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses | select('match', '^10\.0\.59') | list}}
```

result

```
>cat testfile.txt
MyIP = ['10.0.59.100']
```

Question: What filter i need to add, to get IP value as string. or maybe use some other method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the first element of the list if this is what you want

```yaml
MyIP = {{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses | select('match', '^10\.0\.59') | first }}
```

Comment: ```MyIP = 10.0.59.100```
Thank you